# Is there a Mongolian ritual of throwing water in front of someone departing on a journey?

Tags: cultural-history, mongolia

Is there a Mongolian (or Tengrist) ritual of throwing water in front of someone before they set off on a journey? Or is that just a Turkish thing?

Comment: Interesting question, but why ask it on History SE?

Comment: I couldn't figure out a better place to put it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, I really don't know, but as it isn't about history, it will probably end up being closed as off-topic here.

Comment: @DanielBensen - I might be able to help but I **need clarification** on the "throwing water (before a journey)". Can you provide more context/details, i.e. info, link, video, etc? For a start, it would not be from the concept of _Tenggeri_ or _Tenggiri_, which is the _Heavenly Sky_, somewhat similar to "Mandate from Heaven", or the resulting shamanistic belief.

Comment: @JAsia thank you! Is there a ritual involving water and someone setting out on a journey? In Bulgaria, you throw water in front of someone before they walk away. In Turkey (apparently) you throw water across the hood of someone's car before they drive away.

Comment: @DanielBensen - Not really clear to me that you've described a _ritual_, looks more like custom. I had in mind a fairly formal Daoist ritual, involving water blessing -- which has a long history in some parts of East Asia, and is related to the Daoist tenet of [**Wu Wei ( 無爲).**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_wei). On Mongolian approach to Tengrism, see ["_Heaven, Earth and Mongols by Rachewiltz_"](http://altaica.ru/LIBRARY/rachewiltz/Rachewiltz_Heaven%2C%20Earth%20and%20the%20Mongols%202007.pdf) (pdf). Sorry, can't help with more.

Comment: Iranians do this too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a Mongolian, the first thing to come to mind is, spraying milk right after someone special such as a family member leaves. For book sources. I believe it was described by Jack Weatherford in "Genghis Khan and the Making of the Modern World" or "The secret history of Mongol Queens".
I find this interesting as "suu" means milk in Mongolian and water in Turkish, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you turoo! That milk-spraying sounds a lot like the Turkish (and Bulgarian) water-splashing. In the end I didn't include it in my story (which you can find in the Tales from Alternate Earths 2 anthology https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41085653-tales-from-alternate-earths-2) I enjoyed both of those Weatherford books. And I believe "su" is Turkish for "water," yes! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

I'm Jewish from Uzbekistan (Samarkand), and in my family growing up, we always threw a cup of water right as the car pulled away for a long drive.

Comment: Interesting, but can you provide more details? Did you see or hear about others doing this?

Comment: That's exactly what we do in Bulgaria and what (apparently) is done in Turkey! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a Tengrist ritual that - as many others - is foundin both Muslim and Christian countries that have Tengrist past. Tengrism gradually integrated in both Christianity and Islam. There are also a number of rituals revolving around 40 days - 40 days after a child is born and 40 days after someone has died. They are very common in the Balkans and in the Arab world - and people usually think that they are Christian or Muslim - they are in fact Tengrist and have been brought in Europe separately by the Bolgars and by the Turks. Usually, as a rule of thumb, rituals that are common both in the Balkans and in the Middle East, are of Tengrist origin.

Comment: Thank you! This question was for a short story that later appeared in the second Tales of Alternate Earths anthology. It includes a large, Tengrist country. More here: https://www.danielmbensen.com/tales-from-alternate-earths.html